# Multi-language syntax highlighting in Atom

Tags: syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I am doing a project where I have files which have markdown and perl in it. I would like to be able to syntax highlight both of them, is it possible in atom?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but it is not perfect.

There is a [well-written post about this on discuss.atom.io](https://discuss.atom.io/t/better-syntax-highlighting/7176/4). Basically, you have to manually edit the language package (like [`language-markdown`](https://atom.io/packages/language-markdown) or [`language-perl`](https://atom.io/packages/language-perl)) and add an extra grammar rule by referring to another language.

For example, adding

```
{
    'begin': '`'
    'beginCaptures':
      '0':
        'name': 'punctuation.definition.string.begin.coffee'
    'end': '`'
    'endCaptures':
      '0':
        'name': 'punctuation.definition.string.end.coffee'
    'name': 'string.quoted.script.coffee'
    'patterns': [
      {
        'include': 'source.js'
      }
    ]
  }
```

to [`language-coffee-script`](https://atom.io/packages/language-coffee-script) enables [syntax-highlighting](/questions/tagged/syntax-highlighting) of [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) between two instances of `` (`) ``.